# Star trek episode with Mr. Spock holding an "exotic animal"

Tags: identify-this-episode, star-trek

I have found on 9-gag this still:

[image]

with Mr. Spock holding an "exotic animal" which is actually an annoyed dog in a unicorn-suit (sorta...).

From which episode is it? Unless it is a photoshopped image (can't really trust 9-gag...)

Comment: Did you try a reverse image search?

Comment: Indeed, a reverse search will get you there (*The Enemy Within*, season 1, episode 5). Cute pooch. :)

Comment: @Catija it sends me to reddit, imgur and such. I read some of the comments, but I couldn't find the source of the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you Google "Spock Unicorn Dog", it seems that this image is from episode called "*[The Enemy Within](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Enemy_Within_%28Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series%29)*" (Season 1 Episode 5).

> Scott assists in beaming a dog-like animal specimen from the planet, but he and the others are surprised when two identical creatures materialize - one completely docile and the other vicious.

From IMDb's [synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708463/synopsis) page:

> First, after repairs are made, they try the experiment with a unicorn-dog, which was split into two when it was beamed up. One half of the unicorn-dog was peaceful, the other was snarling and biting.

Also, this image appears on a site called [thegeektwins.com](http://www.thegeektwins.com/2013/01/caption-this-spock-and-unicorn-dog.html#.VZwxJudBCM8) in a caption contest where it specifically notes the source of the image:

> While the original Star Trek: The Original Series series had a lot of things going for it (a great cast, engaging characters, thought-provoking science-fiction, resonant themes), I don't think anyone would list "big budget" among them. Nowhere was it more evident than in "The Enemy Within," when an alien creature was depicted by a little dog in a fur coat and a horn.

Comment: No need to qualify your answer with "it seems". The image is a screen cap from that episode some 17 minutes in (just checked it on Netflix). Kirk (holding the animal) converses with Spock in the transporter room regarding his hold on leadership; Kirk hands the animal to Spock and exits.

Comment: @AnthonyX that's... just how I write.